# how do you configure apache with django?

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to configure django with apache. I do see two different site-packages directory in my system:

```
 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
 /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
```

The django and all the necessary libraries are installed in

```
/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
```

How do I ensure apache reads the path as default python library?

Comment: I highly recommend you use [`mod_wsgi`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). Especially, using a virtualenv will solve the issue you have, among others you don't have yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about that. Python will look for packages in both of those paths.

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-unix-the-prefix-scheme):

> First, consider that many Linux distributions put Python in `/usr`, rather than the more traditional `/usr/local`. This is entirely appropriate, since in those cases Python is part of "the system" rather than a local add-on. However, if you are installing Python modules from source, you probably want them to go in `/usr/local/lib/python2.X` rather than `/usr/lib/python2.X`.

You just need to configure the path to your django project's `wsgi.py` file. You can do it like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite

<Directory /path/to/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Note that wherever I've written `mysite/mysite` it means your project's inner directory (which contains settings, wsgi, etc. files)

**EDIT**

In case you want to see if those folders are in Python's *search path*, you can do this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
# outputs python search path
```